# Magento 2 how to get order collection

Tags: magento2, orders, collection

how to get order collection in custom module ? like My Orders collection in customers dashboard (frontend). this collection how to get?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refer the following function:

> Class : Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History

```
 /**
     * @return bool|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```

If have any issues. Please comment. I will try to resolve.

Comment: how to get attribute value from order details ? because I want to get order collection by filtration of custom attribute.

Comment: @Ishu: I don't have a solution for this new requirement, as sales order resource models are bit complex. I suggest to post this new question so that others may help you on it.

Comment: Can we filter by sku ?

Answer (score 21):

You can used this code in your custom module.

```
<?php
namespace 'YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME_SPACE';

class YOURCALSS extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory 
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    }
   public function YOURFUNCTION()
   {
       $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }


   }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Vasoya it is working and useful for many developers and good job bro..

Answer (score 8):

> Note: When I first came across this question, I was just beginning and
>   I couldn't understand how to use the above answers in my code. That's
>   why I'm writing this answer as a reference to any beginner who comes
>   across this question like me.

Here is how I managed to get all orders in the past 3 days that have their statuses as 'pending'

```
<?php
namespace <Your Namespace Here>;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Test {
    protected $logger;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-3 day');

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(
                'status',
                'pending',
                'eq'
            )->addFilter(
                'created_at',
                $date->format('Y-m-d'),
                'gt'
            )->create();

        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
            //Your Code Here
            $this->logger->info("Order# {$order->getIncrementId()} - Creation Date: {$order->getCreatedAt()}");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wondering if this way is better from using the collection.. pros/cons ?

Comment: pros : still working after Magento upgrades

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
namespace CustomAPI\MyRecentOrder\Model;
use CustomAPI\MyRecentOrder\Api\MyRecentOrderInterface;

//use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as productCollectionFactory;
//use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface as productRepository;
class MyRecentOrder implements MyRecentOrderInterface 
{
    //protected $logger;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;



    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder



        ) 
        {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;


        }

    public function getMyRecentOrder($email,$pagesize,$curpage){

        try{
           $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(
                'status',
                'pending',
                'eq'
            )->addFilter(
                'customer_email',
                 $email
            )->create();

            $orders = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                       ->setPageSize($pagesize)
                       ->setCurPage($curpage);
            return $orders->getData();

            }     

                  catch(\Exception $e){
                  $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
                  return false;
        }

    }
}

//
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you:

```
<?php
namespace Muzammil\HelloWorld\Block;
class Products extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
  
     protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory 
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }


   public function getOrderCollection()
   {
       $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition); //Add condition if you wish
     
     return $collection;
     
    }


   public function getOrderCollectionByCustomerId($customerId)
   {
       $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)
         ->addFieldToSelect('*')
         ->addFieldToFilter('status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )
         ->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
 
     return $collection;

    }
}
```