# Get order collection past one hour completed orders magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, collection

How to add filter last past one-hour completed orders collection in Magento 2?

```
  $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter('is_process', $isprocess)
        ->addSortOrder($this->sortBuilder->setField('entity_id')
            ->setAscendingDirection()->create())
        ->setPageSize(3)->setCurrentPage(1)->create();

    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $ordersList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    $ordersList->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));

    return $ordersList;
```

Comment: May be this link is useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160604/magento-2-how-to-get-order-collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
             ->addFilter('is_reward_process', $isrewardprocess)
             ->addSortOrder($this->sortBuilder->setField('entity_id')
             ->setAscendingDirection()->create())
             ->setPageSize(50)->setCurrentPage(1)->create();
    
   $ordersList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
         
   $ordersList->getSelect()->where(
                    new \Zend_Db_Expr('TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `created_at`)) >= ' . $canceltime * 60 * 60)
                );
    
    return $ordersList;
```

Comment: hmm ok, so let me get something checked first, the way I understood the problem and also how this evolved in your answer as well, you are extracting the orders created within an hour and completed in between. is this what you need? or is it that you need to identify which orders were marked as complete within the last hour?

Comment: it's ok .... Thanks a lot @DianaBotean

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

here's a shorter version to build the time filter:

```php
// get current time - 1 hour
$time = date(
    "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    (time() - 3600)
);

// then use it as a filter
(...)
->addFieldToFilter(
   'created_at',
   [
      'gteq' => $time
   ]
);
```

as for the status filtering, it should be something like this:

```php
->addFieldToFilter(
    'status',
    [
        'eq' => 'complete'
    ]
);
```